# How to assign value of one variable to name of another? [JavaScript, Vue.js]

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I have 2 JSON arrays

```
"feeds":[
  {
     "created_at":"2021-11-28T00:11:38Z",
     "entry_id":17901,
     "field1":"16.40000",
     "field2":"45.50000",
     "field3":"16.06250",
     "field4":"5.20000",
     "field5":"49.79300",
     "field7":"1",
     "field8":"390267909"
  }
]
```

and

```
 "measurements":[
   {
      "user_id":1,
      "measurements_id":1,
      "fieldId":1,
      "name":"Unutrašnja temperatura vazduha",
      "unit":"°C",
      "url":"inner-temp.png"
   }]
```

So in my code when I want to access value of field1 I do `myField=feeds.field1` and then value of `myField` is `16.4000`. But now I need to add those values dynamically, depending on the `fieldId` property value from second JSON array `measurements`.

Basically, I need something like: `myField='feeds.field'+measurements.fieldId` and then again `myField` should be `16.4000`.

Comment: Is the JSON data formatted like that? Or is it truncated? If it is like that, parsing it will throw an error.

Comment: I just cut the most important parts, to simplify question.

Comment: Consider using the square bracket notation. `feed[\`${field}${measurements.fieldId}\`]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use bracket notation to access object members like so:

```
myField = feeds['field' + measurements.fieldId];
```

[You can read more about it on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#bracket_notation)